# Angular Fire with Universal SSR | Everything works, but the problem is while building my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, angular-universal

This might be a duplicate question and there are a lot of questions similar to this one on GitHub as well. They all suggest workarounds that just doesn't work for me. I'm new to frontend frameworks and it's the curiosity that fueled me to do everything I did. So please be easy on me if this is a silly mistake.

Versions:

```
node: 12.12.0
angular cli: 8.3.23
@angular/fire: ^5.4.2
firebase: ^7.13.1
```

So as I said, everything works fine in dev mode, everything, not a single problem. The error shows up when I run a script 'universal-ssr@0.0.0 serve:ssr' where 'universal-ssr' being the name of my project. I've tried a lot of stuff but none came even close to solve the issue.

The script I executed:

`npm run staging`

The issue:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'memcpy' in '/home/de-10/VS Code Workspace/oms-v3/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist'
.
.
.
/home/de-10/VS Code Workspace/oms-v3/dist/server/main.js:226508
        throw new Error("package.json does not exist at " + package_json_path);
        ^

Error: package.json does not exist at /home/de-10/VS Code Workspace/oms-v3/dist/package.json
    at Object../node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js.exports.find (/home/de-10/VS Code Workspace/oms-v3/dist/server/main.js:226508:15)
.
.
.
npm ERR! universal-ssr@0.0.0 staging: `npm run build:ssr-staging && npm run serve:ssr`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the universal-ssr@0.0.0 staging script.
```

package.json :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "staging": "npm run build:ssr-staging && npm run serve:ssr",
    "build:ssr-staging": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-staging && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles-staging": "ng build --c=staging --build-optimizer=true --stats-json  && ng run universal-ssr:server --bundleDependencies all"
  }
}
```

One of the workaround was to remove `--bundleDependencies all` or replace it with `--bundleDependencies none` but that doesn't work for me. It does successfully build though but when I move the dist folder and execute `node dist/server.js` the following error shows up:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'
Require stack:
- /home/de-10/Desktop/dist/server/main.js
- /home/de-10/Desktop/dist/server.js
.
.
.
at __webpack_require__ (/home/de-10/Desktop/dist/server/main.js:20:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/de-10/Desktop/dist/server/main.js',
    '/home/de-10/Desktop/dist/server.js'
  ]
}
```

I also tried installing `grpc` and `@grpc/proto-loader` as someone suggested but nope, it doesn't work.

Another workaround was to add a set of packages to angular.json > architect.server.options:

```
"externalDependencies": [
   "grpc",
   "@grpc/proto-loader",
   "@angular/fire/firestore",
   "firebase/firestore"
]
```

So when I try to do that, I get:

`Property externalDependencies is not allowed.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good effort on the formatting, but I think it's easier to use the triple-backtick method and tell SO which formatter to use. Take a look at how I've rearranged it. Not that this is an exact science -- the error output is more art than anything else as there are no real formatters that fit that stuff so I usually opt for the shell formatted (`sh`). If you're unsure, you can see my changes by editing the post again (you don't have to save it).

Comment: Thanks for your patience as well. It feels good to learn new stuff every day.

Comment: @KeshavramKuduwa how did you solve this?